# UI progressbar bug C#

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have a bug with a progressbar, and I don't know what to do with it.

I have a for cycle (or loop) that runs from 0 to 100, and just reports his progress, and then sleeps 100ms:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

And in the progresschanged event handler method in addition to some other stuff there are two "if"s:

```
if (matchProgressBar.Value == 50)
{
    OnHalfTime(); //listBox1.Add("Halftime!");
}
if (matchProgressBar.Value == 100)
{
    OnFullTime(); //listBox1.Add("Full time!");
}
```

The two "unknown" method is adds a line to a listBox. In the first case: "Halftime!"; and in the second: "Full time!". And after both lines there's the same "Thread.Sleep(5000);" //You know, just because you need some break in halftime :) //

But the problem is that however the listBox1 has already been updated, but the GUI sleeps 5 secs before the progressbar has updated. (So the program stucks at 49% and 99% for 5 secs.)

Question: Can I do something to fix this?

Comment: Why do you have `Thread.Sleep` in the progress changed handler.  Sleeping in the UI thread is bad, and you need to remove that, but I don't know what should replace it since you don't explain what the purpose of that `Sleep` call is.  I also find it odd that you omit the clearly important and problematic section of code.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't call `Sleep()` in the UI thread.  Consider rearranging things so that you pause and then resume your background thread, if that's the intention.

To force the progress bar to update, call `Invalidate()` and `Update()`.  Example:

```
matchProgressBar.Invalidate();
matchProgressBar.Update();
```

**EDIT (clarification for @Servy comment):**

Just to be clear, I've provided two alternatives above.  The preferred way to resolve the problem is to remove the `Sleep()` in the UI thread and instead let the background thread be responsible for "pausing" at the appropriate times.  The second alternative, using `Invalidate()` and `Update()` prior to calling `Sleep()` in the UI thread, would likely work in this specific instance, but is really a hack and will not hold up well from a maintenance standpoint (i.e., prone to break with future code changes), and has other undesirable attributes as well.  If at all possible, please use the first method.

Comment: I just don't quite have it in me to +1 an answer that uses `Invalidate`/`Update` to get around sleeping in the UI thread, even if the first half is indeed the appropriate solution.

Comment: I think his idea is good but it would probably be safer to use a Task (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) and use the Task.Delay method to control how long to wait. I have only just recently been informed of Tasks so I haven't used them in application yet, but from what I'm to understand, they are much safer than Threads to control.

Comment: Just as an aside, calling `Refresh()` is equivalent to calling `Invalidate()` and then `Update()`.